# How do I write this in a single line of code?

Tags: php

This is a task from the Codecademy Learn PHP. The task is to print this out to a single line of code.

```
<?php
    function first()
    {
      return "You did it!\n";
    }
    
    function second()
    {
      return "You're amazing!\n";
    }
    
    function third()
    {
      return "You're a coding hero!\n";
    }
    
    // Write your code below:
```

Here is what I have:

```
echo first() + second() + third();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please look for [PHP String Operators](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php) The concatenation operator is `.` so you need:

```
echo first() . second() . third();
```

[Look live example](https://phpize.online/sql/mysql57/undefined/php/php8/7d23f2953c608ea652d2d23ac09366ee/)